# Convert BeginInvoke to async/await

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, begininvoke

I have a function `apiClient.OrderSend` that must be called inside the "GUI" thread, so I created this function

```
   private void RunOnUIThread(Action action)
   {
        this.BeginInvoke(action);
   }
```

I then have a function that needs to `return` an `int` like this

```
    int AlgoSendOrder(MT4Order order)
    {
        int retVal = -1;

        RunOnUIThread(() =>
        {
            retVal = apiClient.OrderSend(order.Symbol, (TradeOperation)order.OrderSide, order.Volume,
                                        order.Price, order.AllowedSlippage ?? default(int),
                                        order.PriceToStopLoss ?? default(double),
                                        order.PriceToTakeProfit ?? default(double));
        });

        return retVal;
    }
```

The problem is that `AlgoSendOrder` returns before `apiClient.OrderSend` returns, so `retVal` is always -1 to the client of this function.

It seems that this a reasonable change is to use `await-async` pair execute the function in the GUI thread, and to have the desired effect of waiting for the return value. However I can't seem to get it to work.

Seems like I should be able to rework `RunOnUIThread` to use `async-await`

```
public async Task RunOnUIThreadAsync()
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        // what do I put here?
    }
    {
        … // like before (but can now use `await` expressions)
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems counter intuitive to run a blocking task (that takes long) on the UI thread. Would it be possible to run the API call in the background and updating the UI separately once the API call returned?

Comment: @Phillipe, yes winform, but the caller not guaranteed to be on GUI thread, hence the wrap of begininvoke

Comment: @Onots, no apiclient.OrderSend crashes outside GUI thread. Also, the whole thing takes less than 1 millisecond.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an async method to perform the background task in a separate thread. Note the Task.Run in the sample below:

```
async Task<int> AlgoSendOrderAsync(MT4Order order)
{
    int retVal = -1;

    //Doing this on another thread using Task.Run
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        retVal = apiClient.OrderSend(order.Symbol, (TradeOperation)order.OrderSide, order.Volume,
                                    order.Price, order.AllowedSlippage ?? default(int),
                                    order.PriceToStopLoss ?? default(double),
                                    order.PriceToTakeProfit ?? default(double));
    });

    return retVal;
}
```

Call this method on the UI thread like this:

```
async void onButtonClickOnWhatever(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    int result = await AlgoSendOrderAsync(order);
    //Here you are on the UI thread, you can update your controls here safely
}
```